# scipy.linalg.svd: shapes of VT and U: what is full_matrices and why is it needed?

Tags: python, scipy, svd

[scipy.linalg.svd](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.svd.html) decomposes "any" array A to U, s, VT
An example would be:

```
from numpy import array
from scipy.linalg import svd
import numpy as np

# define a matrix
A = np.arange(200).reshape((100,2))
print ('A.shape',A.shape)
U, s, VT = svd(A)
print ('U.shape',U.shape)
print ('s.shape',s.shape)
print ('VT.shape',VT.shape)
s_diag = np.zeros((100,2))
np.fill_diagonal(s_diag, s) 
print(np.allclose(A,np.dot(np.dot(U,s_diag),VT)))
```

[image].png

When `A.shape == (m,n)`, the default shapes of the arrays U and VT are  and (m,m) and (n,n). I note there is an option (`full_matrices`) to what I would expect as for example: 
[image]
What I cannot understand is **why U and VT would ever need to be (m,m) and (n,n)?** When multiplying, since s_diag is a "diagonal", the only parts of U and VT tables used are the smaller anyway... (e.g. in the example the size of U could just be 100,2...)

Answer (score 4):

After some [wikipedia reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) and some math recollection, it turns out that this has a valid reason to be so...

So, first obvious reason is that depending on which one is smaller, m or n, one of the tables will need to be full anyways.

Now the mathematical reason is in math theory both U and VT are [orthonormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormality), meaning that `np.dot(U,U.T)` is equal to `np.dot(U.T,U)` is equal to the unit Matrix. The same holds for VT. Therefore they are  of shapes (m,m) and (n,n)

This seems not to be useful for my case, where i want to do dimentionality reduction, but SVD has many other uses, such as finding pseudo inverse tables.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, I was very interested in this answer.